# Creating two separate registration forms in Web2py?

Tags: python, web2py

So I want to create two registration forms side by side. One for users and other for employees. So basically the index page will have something like "Click here if you are a user" and "Click here if you are an employee". It will redirect to the appropriate registration page. I want the user registration to be just like how the built in web2py registration is. For the employee registration I want the following fields:

1. Name 2. Store Name 3. Store Type 4. Zip Code

I am really new to web2py so not sure how to implement this. Could someone please tell me how I should go about creating a registration.py model for this? Also I want the index to redirect to these two links as appropriate:

```
[app]/user/register
[app]/employee/register
```

Also what would my controller file look like? Would I need a separate controller for user and the employee?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear. Do you want to show two forms side by side OR do you want to redirect to the appropriate registration page?

Let's assume you opt for the second option as you described in your question. I'm also assuming that for whatever reason, employees and users are not the same as i understood from your question.

First create the employee table in models:

```
STORE_TYPE = ['Department store', 'Discount store', 'Warehouse store', 'Mom-And-Pop', 'Boutique']

db.define_table('employee',
                Field('first_name'),
                Field('last_name'),
                Field('store_name'),
                Field('store_type', requires=IS_IN_SET(STORE_TYPE)),
                Field('zip_code'),
                auth.signature)
```

Then in the controller just ask the user if she is an employee or user:

```
def index():
    form = SQLFORM.factory(Field('user_or_employee', requires = IS_IN_SET(['user', 'employee']))).process()
    if form.accepted:
        if form.vars.user_or_employee == 'user':
            redirect(URL('user/register'))
        elif form.vars.user_or_employee == 'employee':
            redirect(URL('employee_register'))
    return locals()
```

If the user is a 'user' then you'll redirect them to the user/register as wished. if they are an 'employee' then redirect them to index/employee_register

```
def employee_register():
    form = SQLFORM(db.employee)
    if form.process().accepted:
        redirect(URL('welcome')) # or whatever function you wish...
    return locals()
```

From there you can take it by yourself.

Don't forget to create the views. For index and for default/employee-register.html. In both views you should include the forms you've created, something like that:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h2>Please Register to Continue</h2>
{{=form}}
```